# Don't add exact same 3 columns value in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to add a CSV file in a database. But after I add one file, some weeks later I need to add a new update of the file. Problem is: Duplicate rows are added.

I don't have an ID for rows so I have to see if they are the same with 'City', 'Address' and 'Location Name'. Only if the 3 are matching then we dont put the new row in database.

I tried `IGNORE` but it seems to only work whit an ID as primary key (and I don't have primary key).

I also read a 'multiple primary key' thread but I did not succeed to create it.

My actual code is (Codeigniter):

```
$query = $this->db->query('
            LOAD DATA INFILE "'.$path.'fichier/'.$fichier.'"  
            INTO TABLE location FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" 
            LINES TERMINATED BY "'.$os2.'" 
            IGNORE 1 LINES ('.$name[1].','.$name[2].','.$name[3].','.$name[4].','.$name[5].','.$name[6].','.$name[7].','.$name[8].','.$name[9].','.$name[10].','.$name[11].','.$name[12].','.$name[13].','.$name[14].','.$name[15].','.$name[16].','.$name[17].','.$name[18].','.$name[19].')');
```

Comment: If your data in table and your data in file are the same, you can use TRUNCATE TABLE and then load all data from file (old and new data).

Comment: @hokusai I have 3 different files :s So I can't delete data and add one updated file because the 2 other will be gone :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone want to know how I finally succeed:

I created a unique in phpmyadmin. And then I used a `IGNORE` on my request.

```
ALTER TABLE location
   ADD CONSTRAINT iu_location UNIQUE( col1, col2, col3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, best would be to load your updated CSV in a *staging table*. Once all data loaded, do a `LEFT JOIN` with your actual table and find out all the new records and then insert only those new records to your main table (OR) Once all data loaded, flush all the data in main table with this new staging table.

Per your comment:

Yes, one you have loaded data to new table perform a `LEFT JOIN` with your main table (something like below)

```
select staging_table.id
from staging_table
left join main_table on staging_table.id = main_table.id
where main_table.id is null;
```

Comment: How can I 'find out new records' ? Is LEFT JOIN comparing data from both table?

Comment: Ok but like I said I don't have an id so, can I use left join with more than one columns with something like: `left join main_table on staging_table.city = main_table.city and staging_table.address = main_table.address and staging_table.location_name = main_table.location_name` to be sure the 3 are the same?

Comment: @Firefly, yes you can absolutely. using either `OR` / `AND` condition. what shown in answer is an sample and may not be the actual one which would work for you.

Comment: I'll try ! To be sure I understand well. I don't need to put "ignore" because the new table will overwrite the old one right? And the `where main_table.id is null;` is to take all the rows because we will never have an ID right?

Comment: @Firefly, that's right. Again, read the answer properly so that you understand what I suggested. Point here is *loading the data in staging table ... compare ... then insert into new table*

Comment: I tried `SELECT table_standing.City_Town_Locality AND table_standing.Address AND table_standing.Location_Name
            FROM table_standing
            LEFT JOIN table_standing on table.City_Town_Locality = table_standing.City_Town_Locality AND table.Address = table_standing.Address AND table.Location_Name = table_standing.Location_Name` And the reverse too (table in case of table_standing and table_standing in case of table) I have weird errors like "Not unique table/alias: 'table_standing'"

Comment: And I add the data on table_standing first